# verifying If an object is present in the session's array

Tags: javascript, node.js

here I'm pushing `product_detail` to an empty array product. At first I'm checking if the array is empty, If so the json data is pushed into the array and updated with session. If not I want to verify if the there exists an object with the id, if so it wont push it. but the condition is not becoming true. Dont know what I'm missing or I'm putting the condition wrongly

```
var product_details = {
    product_id: product._id,
    user_id: user_id,
};
if (product.length !== 0) {
    if (req.session.product.forEach(function(data) {
        (data.product_id == req.params._id)
    })) {
        return res.send("product already present ");
    }
    product.push(product_detail);
    req.session.product = product;
    return res.send(req.session.product);
}
product.push(product_detail);
req.session.product = product;
console.log(req.session);
return res.send(req.session.product);
});
```

Comment: the `forEach` shouldn't be inside the condition , it should be the condition inside the loop

Comment: You provided not enough background/ explanation to your code for it to be debugged properly, but you most definetly forgot your `else` expressions and the looped condition won't work at all.

Comment: @AshBringer so I cant have a function as a condition ?

Comment: Sure, but not this one, it does not return anything, thus can't be used to condition, it will always be false, as `forEach` returns `undefined`, which is falsely.

Comment: @ClemensHimmer thanks, I got why I'm getting false

Comment: Does that solve the question? Or is there still an issue with the `else` expressions, or anything else?

Comment: @ClemensHimmer I have to figure out the other way to find if the object is already present, as this wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your nested condition to:

```
var arrayTrue = true;

req.session.product.forEach(function(data) {
    if(data.product_id == req.params._id){
        arrayTrue = false;
    }
});

if(arrayTrue){
    // Doesn't exist...
}
else{
    return res.send("Product already present");
}
```